# What was considered the age of accountability for sin?

Tags: sin

When Jesus said "Father forgive them, for they know not what they do", raised the questions of what the age of accountability for sin was at this time, or was it always a particular age predetermined by our Heavenly Father?

Comment: @Nigel J - I think you mean Psalm 58:3?

Comment: What on earth does the quoted verse have to do with age, or lack thereof ?

Comment: @nigel j ; if you say that babies are estranged from the womb then what happened to Abel or Enoch?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one example that I can think of from the Old Testament where a sepcific age was given.  The age was for those who couldn't go into the promised land (except Joshua and Caleb), meaning those younger were not prohibited from entering.

> "Your carcases shall fall in the wilderness;  and all that were numbered of you, according to your whole number, from twenty years old and upward which have murmured against me.  Doubtless ye shall not come into the land, concerning which I sware to make you dwell therein, save Caleb the son of Jephunneh, and Joshua the son of Nun.  But your little ones, which ye said should be a prey, them will I bring in, and they shall know the land which ye have despised."  Numbers 14:29-31 (KJV)

The next scripture refers to the same group of persons, but refers more to their awarness/knowledge of right and wrong not specifically an age:

> "Moreover your little ones, which ye said should be a prey, and your children, which in that day had no knowledge between good and evil, they shall go in thither, and unto them will I give it, and they shall possess it."  Deuteronomy 1:39 (KJV)

Another scripture that I am aware of also speaks more of there being a point when awareness of right and wrong is learnt, but no age is specifically given:

> "Butter and honey shall he eat, that he may know to refuse the evil and choose the good.  For before the child shall know to refuse the evil and choose the good, the land that thou abhorest shall be forsaken of both their kings."  Isaiah 7:15-16

In terms of the people who were calling for Jesus' to be crucified and then jeering him when he was dying on the cross, those people (whilst being a part of fulfilling God's plan) were not doing the right thing, in terms of their attitude in their hearts towards Jesus - they had murdered him in their hearts.

Paul say in Acts:

> Men and brethren, children of the stock of Abraham, and whosoever among you feareth God, to you is the word of salvation sent.  For they that dwell at Jerusalem, and their rulers, because they knew him not, nor yet the voices of the prophets which are read every sabbath day, they have fulfilled them in condemning him.  Acts 13:26-27

In John, to some of the Pharisees, who thought they could "see" and discern right from wrong, Jesus said:

> ...For judgement I am come into this world, that they which see not might see;  and they which see might be made blind.  And some Pharisees which were with him heard these words, and said unto him, Are we blind also?  Jesus said unto them, If ye were blind, ye should have no sin:   but now ye say, We see; therefore your sin remaineth."  John 9:39-41 (KJV)

By Jesus asking the Father to "forgive them", it was not because of the age of the people, Jesus was following his own example of what he taught his followers:

> "Forgive us our sins, for we also forgive everyone who sins against us."  Luke 11:2 (NIV)
>   "But I say unto you, Love your enemies, bless them that curse you, do good to them that hate you, and pray for them which despitefully  use you, and persecute you;"  Matthew 5:44 (KJV)

Whether those people were forgiven for what they had in their hearts would be another question for posting, unless it has already been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Proverbs 20:11 KJB
"Even a child is known by his doings, whether his work be pure, and whether it be right."

Personally, I have seen children as young 1-1.5 be able to discern right and wrong and make these choices. I believe once you can discern right and wrong you become accountable for your actions.

It seems to me that once you have the ability to do something, you are also given the discernment whether that action is right or wrong.

Answer: very young

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this question as the Bible presents an extremely mature, and nuanced view of the complexity of humanity.  It is true that even young children can discern some right from wrong but many older people cannot understand why some things are sinful.  Here is a sample:

- Ps 51:5 suggests that we are all sinful from birth.  Ps 58:3 says something similar
- Bar mitzvah was (and still is) held at age 12 because such people are supposed to have developed some sense of right and wrong.
- The reference in the people excluded from judgement in the desert wanderings, 20 years and younger suggests another age where greater maturity has developed.  Ex 30:14, 38:26, Num 1:3, etc.  While this may have been as much to do with army service, it required enough moral discernment to understand the subtle difference between murder and killing, as a soldier requires.
- Luke 23:34 is most significant because it discuss older people, teachers of the law and soldiers who could not understand the significance of their actions and that they were so wrong.  See John 9:39-41 for another tricky example.

Therefore, I conclude that there are "sins and sins" - some are simple (eg stealing cookies from the cookie jar) and others much more complex and subtle whose sinfulness is not immediately obvious even to older people.  There is everything in between too.

We mature at different rates and in different ways.  I am sure that we all have sinned in various ways that we have been unaware of sometimes we found out later; and many sins we do not even know about.  God is gracious to us all.

Answer (score 0):

[The Original View of Original Sin](https://www.vision.org/the-original-view-of-original-sin-1140)

Peter Nathan

Quote

> Augustine was challenged by the question that philosophers inevitably
>   posed to Christians: “How could sin have entered the world, if God is
>   good?” Augustine sought to answer this challenge and in so doing
>   adopted many of the philosophers’ ideas.
>
> The result, as evidenced by his writings, was that Augustine
>   reinterpreted the Bible in light of philosophy. With respect to
>   original sin, he understood the account of Adam and Eve as a
>   description of humanity’s fall from grace. They sinned and were
>   punished by God, and thus all subsequent humanity, being at that time
>   biologically present within Adam, was party to the sin. The idea of
>   innate sin and guilt became a widespread doctrine, as is shown by the
>   following words from a popular American schoolbook used in the 17th
>   and 18th centuries: “In Adam’s fall, we sinned all.”
>
> But Augustine did not devise the concept of original sin. It was his
>   use of specific New Testament scriptures to justify the doctrine that
>   was new. The concept itself had been shaped from the late second
>   century onward by certain church fathers, including Irenaeus, Origen
>   and Tertullian. Irenaeus did not use the Scriptures at all for his
>   definition; Origen reinterpreted the Genesis account of Adam and Eve
>   in terms of a Platonic allegory and saw sin deriving solely from free
>   will; and Tertullian’s version was borrowed from Stoic philosophy.
>
> Though Augustine was convinced by the arguments of his earlier
>   patristic peers, he made use of the apostle Paul’s letters, especially
>   the one to the Romans, to develop his own ideas on original sin and
>   guilt. Today, however, it is accepted that Augustine, who had never
>   mastered the Greek language, misread Paul in at least one instance by
>   using an inadequate Latin translation of the Greek original.
>
> In Romans 5, Paul addresses the matter of sin. In verse 12 he states,
>   “Therefore . . . sin came into the world through one man, and death
>   came through sin, and so death spread to all because all have sinned”
>   (NRSV). Later in the chapter, Paul juxtaposes the sin of Adam with the
>   righteousness of Christ: “Just as by the one man’s disobedience the
>   many were made sinners, so by the one man’s obedience the many will be
>   made righteous” (Romans 5:19). In contrast to his contemporary
>   theologians, Augustine drew from his reading of these scriptures that
>   sin was passed biologically from Adam to all his descendants through
>   the sexual act itself, thus equating sexual desire with sin. But why
>   should he have reached this interpretation when marital sexual
>   relations in Jewish society at the time of Christ and Paul were
>   considered honorable and good?
>
> Augustine’s outlook on sex was distorted by ideas from the world
>   outside the Bible. Because so much philosophy was based on dualism, in
>   which the physical was categorized as evil but the spiritual as good,
>   some philosophers idealized the celibate state. Sexual relations were
>   physical and therefore evil.
>
> Augustine’s association with Neoplatonic philosophers led him to
>   introduce their outlook within the church. This had its effect in the
>   development of doctrine. For example, Jesus was considered
>   immaculately conceived—without sin in that His Father was God. But
>   because His mother, Mary, had a human father, she suffered the effect
>   of original sin. In order to present Jesus Christ as a perfect
>   offspring without any inherited sin from either parent, the church had
>   to find a way to label Mary as sinless. They did this by devising the
>   doctrine of her immaculate conception, though this inevitably leads to
>   further questions.
>
> Other babies were not so fortunate. Some eight centuries later the
>   Catholic theologian Anselm extended the implications of Augustine’s
>   concept of original sin and claimed that babies who died, did so as
>   sinners; as sinners, they had no access to eternal life but were
>   condemned to eternal damnation.
>
> The world from which Paul came had a very different view of sexual
>   relations, especially within marriage. Sex was not evil; it was part
>   of the physical creation that God had decreed was good (Genesis 1:31).
>   The writer of the Epistle to the Hebrews supports this view in
>   describing the marital bed as “undefiled”—that is, pure or sacred; in
>   other words, the sexual act did not impair a person’s relationship
>   with God (Hebrews 13:4). The apostle Paul takes the idea further in
>   his First Epistle to the Corinthians, where he instructs married
>   couples not to defraud one another but to render appropriate conjugal
>   dues. He states that in the sexual relationship each partner should
>   focus on providing benefit to the other, not just on his or her own
>   satisfaction. Hence Augustine’s view of sex as sin does not match New
>   Testament teaching. Nor does it coincide with the Old Testament
>   statement that a child does not carry its father’s sin (Ezekiel
>   18:19–20).
>
> Further, Paul would have rejected Augustine’s idea of biological
>   transmission. Paul presents a scenario in which humanity is held
>   captive by a spirit being who enslaves them to sin (2 Corinthians
>   4:4–6; Ephesians 2:1–2). According to Paul, the entire world is held
>   captive to “the prince of the power of the air,” or Satan. Paul
>   mentions that the human spirit can be subject to either the spirit of
>   the world or the Spirit of God (1 Corinthians 2:6–14). He also warns
>   Christians that their battle with sin is against spiritual, not
>   physical, forces (Ephesians 6:10–18).
>
> When Paul speaks of sin “entering” the world, he is addressing the
>   fact that Adam willingly submitted himself to Satan’s already sinful
>   nature, something that Jesus Christ also confronted but rejected
>   (Matthew 4:3–11; Romans 5:19). By this act Adam ensured that his
>   progeny would be under Satan’s rulership and influence. Hence in Psalm
>   51 the author speaks of being conceived in sin. It was not that the
>   act of conception was sin but rather that as a result of conception,
>   he was to enter a world in slavery to sin.
>
> So Paul saw sin within a spiritual domain rather than a biological
>   one. This is reinforced later in his Epistle to the Romans, where he
>   describes humanity as being in a state of bondage to spiritual forces
>   (Romans 6:13–23). The choice for Christians is to become servants of
>   Jesus Christ, something that can be done only through God’s Holy
>   Spirit. It is an individually chosen responsibility rather than a
>   hereditary one.
>
> In his commentary titled The Mystery of Romans, Mark Nanos contrasts
>   the action of Jesus Christ with that of Adam, stating that “unlike
>   Adam [Jesus] did not embrace the voice of the tempter, he did not
>   ‘eat,’ as it were. He heard the word of God, believed, and obeyed.”
>
> Jesus Christ came to replace Satan as the ruler of the world, so that
>   sin, by which humanity is enslaved, could be removed (Romans 16:20).
>   Such freedom is accorded to those God draws to His Son now, but it
>   will be accorded to all who are willing after the return of Jesus
>   Christ. This was one reason the early Church eagerly anticipated
>   Christ’s return—so that all humanity could benefit.
>
> Clearly Augustine’s Neoplatonic, dualistic concept of physical being
>   evil and spiritual being good does not coincide with Paul’s view. This
>   leads us to a second influential idea of Augustine’s relating to sin.
>   He proposed the concept of the “fall of man” as a result of sin. In
>   Augustine’s view, humanity lost its spiritual relationship with its
>   Creator and thus fell to a lower state. Is this an idea that finds
>   support in Paul’s writings?
>
> Paul certainly recognized the lack of a spiritual relationship and saw
>   sin resulting in death (Romans 6:15–18). He saw the world alienated
>   from its Creator (Ephesians 2:12; 4:18), a condition that could be
>   corrected only by the intervention of God. But Paul also saw an
>   opportunity for humanity to be restored to a right relationship with
>   God after losing access to Him in the Garden of Eden. However, this
>   could happen only by becoming a “new creation” in God’s hands. Rather
>   than describing the human condition as “fallen,” Paul may well have
>   thought of the situation as a failure to “rise” to what God had
>   offered. He describes those who reject the truth once they have had a
>   relationship with God as having fallen away (Galatians 5:4, NRSV).
>
> Paul’s view corresponds with the rest of the biblical account in that
>   Genesis records that Adam and Eve were denied access to the tree of
>   life, which would have afforded them eternal life. Thus, although they
>   were cut off or alienated from God because of sin and driven from the
>   Garden of Eden, they had never really engaged the relationship with
>   God that He desired, which would have been accomplished only by eating
>   of the tree of life.
>
> Tragically, Augustine’s misreading and misinterpretation of sin based
>   on looking at Scripture through the prism of dualism is accepted as
>   dogma by most contemporary Christian theologians. The doctrine of
>   original sin owes more to Augustine’s desire to emulate the
>   philosophers than it does to the Scriptures.